# Filtering by 1 boolean value from 2 values from interface

Tags: silverlight, linq, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

Lets say I have a property that `IsRegistrationCompleted`.

I have 2 checkboxes in my filter interface that says:

1. Complete
2. Incomplete

If both are checked, then both complete and incomplete users are retrieved. If just `Complete` is checked, just completed users are retrieved. If none are checked, none are retrieved.

How do I put this logic in linq?

I binded my checkboxes as follows:

```
public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
public bool IsInCompleted { get; set; }
```

My method is:

```
private void GetUsers()
{
        //TODO: Apply filters here.
        var query = _context.GetUsers(); //Returns IQueryable<User>

        _context.Load(query, LoadBehavior.MergeIntoCurrent, LoadApplicantsCompleted, null);
}
```

Using silverlight with WCF Ria Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one query it will look like this:

```
Users.Where(r => (IsCompleted  && r.IsRegistrationCompleted) || (IsInCompleted && !r.IsRegistrationCompleted))
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would work. I think it would be hard to read if you had all the following logic in a single Where statement

```
if(IsCompleted && IsInCompleted)
{
   query = query;
}
else if(IsCompleted)
{
  query = query.Where(u => u.IsRegistrationCompleted);
}
else if(IsInCompleted)
{
    query = query.Where(u => !u.IsRegistrationCompleted);
}
else
{
  query = query.Where(u => false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this yet but something like this might work:

```
(from user in users where IsCompleted && user.IsCompleted select user).Union(from user in users where IsInCompleted && !user.IsCompleted select user).Distinct()
```